# BigQuery UDF Error: Correlated Subquery in Temp Function

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I am currently creating a query with a UDF, that returns similar stores from a restaurant table. I want to utilize the UDF so that I can make life easier for myself when I need to reprint the data for new restaurantid's.

I'm running into this issue everytime I expand the query to have 5+ records in the reference list. It works if I have like 2 or 3 records, but no more.

This is the error, neither myslef or ChatGPT can get to the bottom or find a solution; `Query error: Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN`

The script has 3 stages.

1. Create a core reference list (used so the UDF doesnt send back the same IDs & to trigger the UDF in one select)
2. The UDF, it takes 4 parameters and tries to find a similar store
3. Run the UDF from a select statement for all in the reference list

I have attached the full query I am using for the project below. Any response, suggestions, workarounds would all be greatly appreciated!

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `trial_stores_stg1`;
CREATE TABLE `trial_stores_stg1` AS (

SELECT '' AS restaurantid, '' AS country, '' AS launch_date, "Test" AS chain
UNION ALL SELECT "1", "CA", "2022-04-10", "Test"
UNION ALL SELECT "2", "CA", "2022-04-10", "Test"
UNION ALL SELECT "3", "UK", "2022-04-10", "Test"
);

-- Create a temporary UDF

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION FindSimilarStore(var_restaurantid STRING, var_country STRING, var_launch_date DATE, var_chain STRING)
RETURNS STRING
AS (
  (SELECT AS STRUCT similar.restaurantid AS similar_restaurantid
  FROM (
    SELECT
      dr.restaurantid,
      dr.country,
      AVG(nr_of_orders) AS avg_orders
    FROM
      `dummydata.fact_restaurant_daily_snapshot` ds
      JOIN `dummydata.dim_restaurant` dr ON dr.restaurantid = ds.restaurantid
    WHERE
      -- Exclude the sample restaurants
      dr.restaurantid NOT IN (var_restaurantid)
      AND dr.restaurantid NOT IN (SELECT restaurantid FROM `trial_stores_stg1`)
      AND dr.country = var_country
      AND dr.chain = var_chain
      AND ds.snapshot_dt BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE(var_launch_date), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AND DATE(var_launch_date)
    GROUP BY 1, 2
  ) similar

-- We want similar based on historic daily orders
  ORDER BY ABS(similar.avg_orders - (
    SELECT AVG(nr_of_orders) FROM `dummydata.fact_restaurant_daily_snapshot` ds
    JOIN `dummydata.dim_restaurant` dr ON dr.restaurantid = ds.restaurantid
    WHERE dr.restaurantid = var_restaurantid
  )) / (
    SELECT AVG(nr_of_orders) FROM `dummydata.fact_restaurant_daily_snapshot` ds
    JOIN `dummydata.dim_restaurant` dr ON dr.restaurantid = ds.restaurantid
   WHERE dr.restaurantid = var_restaurantid
  )
  LIMIT 1).similar_restaurantid
);



-- Drop the table if it exists
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `trial_stores`;

-- Create the table
CREATE TABLE `trial_stores` (
    restaurantid STRING,
    country STRING,
    similar_restaurantid STRING
);


--UK
INSERT INTO  `trial_stores`
SELECT
  restaurantid,
  country,
  FindSimilarStore(restaurantid, country, CAST(launch_date as DATE), chain) AS similar_restaurantid
FROM
  `trial_stores_stg1`
  WHERE country = "GB";

--CA
INSERT INTO  `trial_stores`
SELECT
  restaurantid,
  country,
  FindSimilarStore(restaurantid, country, CAST(launch_date as DATE), chain) AS similar_restaurantid
FROM
  `trial_stores_stg1`
  WHERE country = "CA";
```

Comment: Is trial_stores_stg1 the "core reference list" your mentioned?

Comment: Correction, I'm referring to when I run the Insert statements, I can only run some records at a time through FinSimilarStore() . I can do all the IDs at once from the store list @Error_2646